# Why does it not execute the python script properly? Laravel Symfony

Tags: python, laravel, symfony

Error after running python script:

```
The command "D:\Python\python.exe "/scripts/HelloWorld.py"" failed. 
Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: D:\LabToolLaravel\public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ 
Fatal Python error: _Py_HashRandomization_Init: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python Python runtime state: preinitialized
```

```php
    $out = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput();
        $python = "D:\Python\python.exe";
        $process = new Process([$python, '/scripts/HelloWorld.py']);

        $process->run();
        if(!$process->isSuccessful()){
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
            
        }
        
        $out->writeln($process->getOutput());
```

Edit:
If I use shell_exec() it works. I'd like to use Symfony but I guess I'll use shell_exec() for now.

```
$out = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput();

        $output = shell_exec("D:\Python\python.exe D:\Laravel\public\scripts\HelloWorld.py");

        $out->writeln($output);
```